# Waveform of voltage/current at centertap during switching transient

Tags: transformer

I am a HAM radio operator and have an engineering background (but I am 75) and I am building a power supply for a vintage tube transmitter. Power supply output for the high voltage requirement is 435 VDC at 250 mA. The original power supply for the transmitter has a separate transformer for the HV and the transmitter switches the primary (115 VAC input) remotely through the connecting cable.    My power supply will be a full wave, diode rectifiers (not bridge) and capacitor input filter. I plan to "turn on" the HV supply to the transmitter by keying the center tap to ground.  On standby it will be connected to a high impedance resistance (1 MΩ). The keying will be through a relay in the power supply. I am using a solid state relay in the supply to close the center tap circuit to ground. The relay is closing the "open" center to a circuit ground.  What is the 'transient' in the center tap circuit when opening and closing?

Comment: The same as if you switched it at any other point in the circuit -- a large inrush current to charge the filter capacitors, then steady pulses of current to recharge them at the AC peaks. The details of the initial inrush pulse depend on where you are in the AC cycle when it happens.

Comment: It might help to draw a schematic of what you intend (resistor/capacitor button on the edit toolbar). But if I can guess from your word picture - your centre tap should rectify itself to -435 V when it's not connected to ground. Correct?